# mysql stored procedure outfile

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, file-io

I am trying to write SP query results to file nad get a consistent error code: 1086 File already exists. This is despite the fact that the file name has to be unique because it's containing a random generate number.
Here is part of my code:

```
SET fullOutputPath = CONCAT(user,'_',FLOOR(1000+RAND()*9999),'.txt');

SELECT fullOutputPath;
-- write the resultset to the file
SELECT node_concat 
    INTO OUTFILE ",fullOutputPath,"
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM sn_neighbour_tmp;
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Example:

```sql
...
SET `fullOutputPath` := CONCAT(USER, '_', FLOOR(1000 + RAND() * 9999), '.txt');
SET @`qry` := CONCAT('SELECT `node_concat` 
                          INTO OUTFILE ', `fullOutputPath`, ' 
                          FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' 
                          OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'\' 
                          LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
                      FROM `sn_neighbour_tmp`');
PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
SET @`qry` := NULL;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
...
```